# GNUradio installation, failed to initialise gtk

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

[image: Error Message]

I was trying to install gnuRadio on my windows 10 laptop, with GNURadio Companion-m
All the necessary files are copied correctly in the file path.
When I run the shortcut of the companion, the cmd disappear without opening up anything.
I run some checks and found the error message in the picture.

Could anyone please help. Thank you

Comment: how did you install GNU Radio?

Comment: I was given a folder in my program files that contains everything is needed for GNUradio. And run this shortcut "C:\Program Files\GNURadio-3.7-m\bin\run_gr.bat" gnuradio-companion.py

Comment: yeah, please use an installer.

Comment: Hi, the same problem still persists with the installer